# Outlook: A Script rule how to move a email to a specific folder and copy the headline into the new folder.

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, script, rules

I have a query about how to move my suppliers quotes into a specific folder and automatically create a folder with the specific enquiry number. So the first step is to create the rule and the folder that should be the headline of the enquiry email, then the other quotes should follow the headline in the email.

Answer (score 0):

The first part is easy, you use [rules](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/create-a-rule-HP005242897.aspx). The second part about renaming the subject is either done with rules, or not done at all if the functionality isn't there.